# What is the iptables equivalent to what socat does?

Tags: iptables, proxy, port, port-forwarding, socat

What is the `iptables` equivalent to the following?

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080 TCP:some-random-host-in-another-network.com:80
```

<sub>Now multiple clients can connect to port 8080 of this middle host to actually access `some-random-host-in-another-network.com:80`.
I'm asking to see whether it improves the latency and throughput.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination some-random-host-in-another-network.com:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d some-random-host-in-another-network.com -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

(this is bare minimum, likely you'd want to add permitting rules into filter FORWARD and so on)

This would translate both addresses, source and destination. The "some-random-host-in-another-network.com" will see connections as coming from this host and hide the original source.

Comment: I replaced domain names by their IP addresses. It gives me error: "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name". So I added -t nat to both rules. Is that right? But still it doesn't work as expected. I checked ip forwarding and it is enabled both for the interface and in general. By the way there is no ufw or other firewalls enabled. I'm not sure, but maybe something even very simple should listen on the incoming open port and iptables alone is not enough?

Comment: Rules: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9090 -j DNAT --to-destination 89.43.107.25:7090; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 89.43.107.25 -p tcp --dport 7090 -j MASQUERADE.    Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I forgot `-t nat`. Sorry. I fixed it in the answer. If it fits you, please accept for the question to not wander around as unanswered.

Comment: Thanks. This answer seems to be essentially correct. Apparently I had some other problem, so I ran these beforehand: iptables -F; iptables -t nat -F; iptables -X

Comment: How can I specify the source interface and the destination interface?

Comment: @Sam there are no "source" and "destination", there are "incoming" (through which the packets comes into the system) `-i` and "outgoing" (the one it leaves through) `-o`. But I don't understand why it could be needed in this case.